# Azure Blob Storage Browser in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, azure-storage, file-browser

I would like to make an Azure Blob Storage browser using Silverlight, like CloudBerry Explorer does. I have an Azure Storage account and the keys, but I am still picking which Control I should use to display file list (DataGrid?).

For the coding, how can I fetch the file list from a blob container ?

p.s. I'm using C# , Visual Studio 2010 , Azure Project Web Role + Silverlight Project

Comment: You can go check this answer, it give more detail. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/9026556/431072](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9026556/431072)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed a silverlight upload control that does exactly that. It uploads a file by splitting it into chunks and retries upload of chunks in case of failed upload. Download it from http://blobupload.codeplex.com/ and use it as you want it to.